# Building a Node.js API with Firebase Backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, api, express, google-cloud-firestore

I hope this is OK to post here. I have found quite a few articles regarding Node/Express/Firebase setup. But looking to gain insight into any future issues of building/scaling a custom REST API with a Firebase backend.

My Plan:

- Setup Google Cloud Node.js for hosting my API (built with Express)
- Integrate with an existing Firebase application
- Be able to use the REST API for serving a mobile App, and also custom website plugins etc...

Currently their mobile app is talking directly with Firebase, and i'm recommending we switch to our own API, so when we build products it all runs through the same conversation style.

My questions are:

- Is this good practice?
- We are able to scale (assuming with Google Cloud / Firestore) we should be fine
- Any recommendations on this practice or articles of reading (I have found quite a few, but nothing really in-depth and valuable).

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

There are pros and cons of using Firebase vs a custom API.

### Firebase

#### Pros

- Easy integration of the UI and the database layer
- Integrated authentication and security rules
- Real-time event listeners
- Rapid development time

#### Cons

- Read permissions can only be enforced at document level
- Business logic cannot be applied at this layer (must use Callable Functions or trigger Cloud Functions based on a database write)

### Custom API

#### Pros

- Ability to standardise data models and rules within the API
- Read permissions can be configured down to attribute level

#### Cons

- Requires a custom authorisation layer
- May require a custom authentication service
- Difficult to provide real-time push to clients
- Much slower development time

### Building a custom API

You can build a custom API in Node using something like **Cloud Run** or **Cloud Functions**, then manage it from something like **API Gateway**.  This will give you greater control over a solution built on Firebase's own **Callable Functions**.  However, you'll have to roll your own authentication provider, either by wrapping the Firebase REST API, using Firebase Authentication's Custom Tokens from the Admin SDK or another method to create JWTs.  The question is, will you still need some backwards compatibility for clients to connect directly to Firebase?  Will they only connect through the new API? Or some kind of hybrid model?

Is Multi-Factor Authentication a requirement? Do you anticipate connecting to other auth providers like SAML or OIDC?  Are you looking for a multi-tenant solution?  In which case you may find that you've outgrown some of Firebase's core functionality, but you can upgrade to GCP services like **Identity Platform** which will give you all of the power of GCP, with the benefits of Firebase.

### Final thoughts

I think that I've probably given you more questions than answers.  My feeling is that if this is an internal API to serve your own apps, stick with Firebase.  If you are looking to publish a fully featured API to external users, consider building something custom.  Sometimes, combining the 2 can give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing response! Appreciate your time. The API would hopefully help ourselves but maybe future developers to jump in too. Our goal is to enable "At Checkout" plugins, whether they are in WooCommerce, Shopify, etc... Other features the API to solve monitoring hack attempts, who's trying to hit our server and monitor data easier. My biggest challenge I for-see is the Authentication passthrough with Firebase. There will always be a pro/con to every solution, just trying to find the best path.

Comment: As a regular Firebase user, I support the user of both together. Cloud Functions does not replace a dedicated machine, but you can't get the same level of hydration and scalability from Cloud Functions